# Problem nvidia-settings not saving resolution change after restarting

Tags: nvidia

When i change nvidia-settings(with sudo) resolution from 1920x1080 to 2560x1440 on the advanced tab and click apply, it all works good, when i press save configurations it saves them into /etc/X11/xorg.conf when i open this file from the terminal it seems all updated correctly.

After rebooting everything resets, all the solutions found on internet about mint or other distros doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you not use the built in system settings to change the screen resolution?

Comment: I found that the only solution that works for me is through nvidia settings, i don't know how to achieve the same goal manually with the cli